# Can't multiply correctly measure member by some value MDX query

Tags: mdx

I have a query that shows prices for some goods:

```
member Measures.[Price] as ([Goods].[Good].Properties( "Base price" )),
format_string = "0.000"
member Measures.[Control] as [Goods].[Good].Properties( "IsControlled" )
select 
{(Measures.[Price]),Measures.[Control]} on columns, ...//select goods on rows.
```

Here is the result:

```
Price  Controll

172,19 not
193,54 not
172,57 not
326,49 not
438,77 not
139,25 not
72,11  controlled
165,76 controlled
233,32 not
655,05 not
607,58 not
201,92 not
126,2  not
```

Now I write a second query which for some reason works incorrect and I don't know how to fix it.
Here is the query:

```
member Measures.[Control] as [Goods].[Good].Properties( "IsControlled" )
member Measures.[Price] as 
CASE Measures.[Control] 
WHEN 'Controlled' THEN [Goods].[Good].Properties( "Base price" )
ELSE ([Goods].[Good].Properties( "Base price" )*0.0095)
END
select {Measures.[Price]}
```

The issue is that for prices wich consists of 5 numbers multiply is correct, but if the price consists of 4 numbers multiply is incorrect.
Result:

```
 Price
 163.5805
 183.863
 163.9415
 310.1655
 416.8315
 132.2875
 72,11
 165,76
 221.654
 622.2975
 577.201
 191.824
 11.989
```

Last price should be 119.89 instead of 11.989. I need to get 95% of Base price. How to do that correctly?

Comment: First: you're multiplying by 0.0095? Shouldn't it be 0.95? Second: Is it "Controlled" or "controlled"? On your first example you have it in lower case.

Comment: I was translating query from another language, deal not in a lower case. Here is result of multiplying wich I see in Analysis Server 172.19*0.95 = 16,358.05;   172.19*0.095 = 1,635.81;   172.19*0.0095 = 163.58. It's weard, but it's work this way.(maybe only at my local machine, did't try somewhere else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `TYPED` when working with non-string properties:

```
WITH member Measures.[Control] as [Goods].[Good].Properties( "IsControlled" )
member Measures.[Price] as 
CASE Measures.[Control] 
WHEN 'Controlled' THEN [Goods].[Good].Properties( "Base price", TYPED )
ELSE ([Goods].[Good].Properties( "Base price", TYPED )*0.0095)
END
select {Measures.[Price]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [your cube]
```

If you do not use `TYPED`, `Properties` returns the result converted to a string. If you use `TYPED`, you get the data in the type that it has in the original column of the relational data. See [the documentation for `Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144821.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thank you. I could'nt even think about different types. And I can't understand how is it works 172.19(string)*0.0095(double,float) = 163.58 - here should be type exeption. You solution work like multiply should work(172.19*0.95=163.58).

Answer (score 0):

So, I was trying make this query different ways and found some solution, that helps in my case. Problem was in different number of digits after dot("."). For example 95% of 172.19 it's 172.19*0.0095, but 95% of  126,2 it's 126.2*0.095. Don't know why but in my MDX query it's calculating this way. I was using Visual Basic functions for this solution. Here is my solution:(after dot can be only 1 digit or 2 digits)

```
member Measures.[FixedPrice] as [Goods].[Good].Properties( "Base price" )
member Measures.[Digits] as vba!Len(Right(Measures.[FixedPrice], Len(Measures.[FixedPrice]) - InStr(1, Measures.[FixedPrice], ",")))
member Measures.[Control] as [Goods].[Good].Properties( "IsControlled" )
member Measures.[Price] as 
iif(Measures.[Control] <> 'Controlled' and Measures.[Digits]<2 ,Measures.[FixedPrice]*0.095,
iif(Measures.[Control] <> 'Controlled' and Measures.[Digits]>1,Measures.[FixedPrice]*0.0095,Measures.[FixedPrice]))
, format_string = '#,#0.00'
select {Measures.[Цена]}
```

At result I have all goods with correct 95% price. All time was working with SQL and T-SQL. And it's weard how MDX multiply is working.